# dojox/form/Uploader processing onclick events in disabled state

Tags: javascript, file-upload, dojo

I'm using the `dojox/form/Uploader` that's initially in `disabled` state:

```html
<div class="claro">
    <button id="uploadNode">Upload</button>
</div>
```

```javascript
require(["dojox/form/Uploader"], function(){

var u = new dojox.form.Uploader({
    label:"Uploader", multiple:false, uploadOnSelect:false, disabled: true},
"uploadNode");
u.startup()

})
```

The widgit is obviously displayed as disabled, but you can still click on it and make the upload. It is reproduced on FireFox and IE (11). I've made [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/11x6o017/) for that.

JsFiddle is for version 1.9.3, but it's happening in version 1.10.0.

How can I functionally (not only visually) disable `dojox/form/Uploader`? Is there any workaround or codefix I can apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buttons "disable" css is only inherited from the DOM object by the Uploader widget. All the handlers are initialized at the time of widget creation (i.e. when calling startup() function). And so is the onclick handler was attached during creation of Uploader widget.

Therefore, set the disabled after creating the widget (applies for other widgets too). Although, it might work on few widgets, it is not recommended.

```
u.set('disabled','true'); //after startup() call this
```

Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/11x6o017/1/)